# Typescript / Angular 5 - iteration on a object

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to collect the information from html page through `ngModel` and insert them in an object declared, then make iteration on this object in the HTML page through `ngFor`.

I already made it but it is retrieving the following error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Please, add some code to you question so we could help you out better. Thank you

Comment: ngFor is suitable for arrays or arrays of objects.

Comment: recardo: but the code its very long that the people can confusing,

Comment: @MOHAMED if it's confusing to people here on stackoverflow, I suggest you drop the project

Comment: kboul: thank u kaboul for your answer, the long i'm try to find the way for insert multiple objects in the table collected from ngModel, then take them to exposed in html page, how i do that ?

Comment: @jack: thank u jack, can i just expose my idea, becouse is not a error code, its the way for develop my project, once i get the best way i will start to create the projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `Object.keys` to get keys (gives array of string) and iterate over it. **[See this Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6zj3ei?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Let's say your object is obj:

```
  obj = {
    apple: "A fruit",
    ball: "A thing to play with"
  }

  get keys(): string[] {
    return Object.keys(this.obj);
  }
```

In your template:

**For keys only:**

```
 <div *ngFor="let key of keys">{{ key }}</div>
```

gives:

```
apple
ball
```

---

**For values only:**

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">{{ obj[key] }}</div>
```

gives:

```
A fruit
A thing to play with
```

---

**For Keys and values:**

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">{{ key }} : {{ obj[key] }}</div>
```

gives:

```
apple : A fruit
ball : A thing to play with
```

Comment: tnx tnx very much tika, this is useful solution, thank u also because u have could understand my idea.

Comment: how i display just (apple: "A fruit") and not others ??

Comment: @MOHAMED See the examples above